# Loop: This method must return a result of type boolean

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the error I get:

> This method must return a result of type boolean

And this is the code:

```
public boolean seleccionar(Aeronave otra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.as.length; i++) {
        if (otra != null && !otra.equals(this.as[i]) && otra.amenazadaPor(this.as[i])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that it is possible that the for-loop will loop through all elements and eventually reach the end and no result is returned. In this case we return false to ensure this.

```java
public boolean seleccionar (Aeronave otra) {
    for (int i=0; i < this.as.length; i++) {
        if (otra !=null && !otra.equals(this.as[i]) && otra.amenazadaPor(this.as[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `return false` before the last brace.  Your function doesn't return anything if `this.as.length == 0`, and Java is giving a compile error because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will exit on first loop element. But when array `this.as` is empty, so loop will not execute, then your function is missing a return value -therefore compiler does not allow this.

To solve this issue, simply move return `false after` the loop ends.

```
public boolean seleccionar (Aeronave otra) {
    for (int i=0; i < this.as.length; i++) {
       if (otra !=null && !otra.equals(this.as[i]) && otra.amenazadaPor(this.as[i])) {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false; // if no elements are matching loop condition, return false
 }}
```